# When nominal interest rates reach zero bound,why inflation will turn to have a positive relation with output gap?

Tags: macroeconomics, monetary-policy, inflation, interest-rate

[image]

From the graph, inflation has a negative relation with output gap when interest rates are higher than zero but turn to a positive relation when reach zero.
I cannot understand why the relationship changes when rates reach zero.

Furthermore, why central banks commit to keeping  interest rates low for an extended period is a solution to avoid deflation trap?